# how to match a second group with regex and php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

i have this scenrio:

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ut dapibus justo. (Aliquam et) (ornare tellus).`

i would like to extract `(ornare tellus)` witch is the 2nd set of parenthesis using regex and php.

the parenthesis can contain letters and numbers

any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for the second set of parenthesis or for the last set of parenthesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
preg_match('/^.+\(([^)]+)\)/', $string, $match);
echo $match[1],"\n";
```

Comment: This pattern give the last parenthesis before the end of the string or a newline. That works in the present example string, but not with newlines before the second group of parenthesis or with more than two groups of parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of dynamic looknbehind lookup here is how you do it:

```
$s = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ut dapibus justo. (Aliquam et) (ornare tellus).';
if (preg_match('/\([^)]*\)[^(]*\(([^)]*)\)/', $s, $arr))
   echo $arr[1]; // ornare tellus
```